# Webelement on salesforce page is not identified when running selenium script

Tags: selenium, salesforce-lightning

I have a web element with xpath //button[@name='FinServ__FinancialAccountRole__c.Add_ITR']

Add ITR

[image: Element on Salesforce Page]

This button element is correctly identified in browser console using developer tools in chrome. Chrome version is 92.0.4515.159
[image: Element correctly identified in browser tool]

But same element is not identified when running the script. I have checked there is no iframe or frame in the page. Element is not identified even with Javascript.
[image: Element not identified when running the Selenium script]

Appreciate any pointers to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It could be, cause `FinServ__FinancialAccountRole__c` can be dynamic in nature, did you see in automation windows that we have a unique entry for

```
 //button[@name='FinServ__FinancialAccountRole__c.Add_ITR']
```

if not, you can try with text itself.

```
//button[text()='Add ITR']
```

also have a proper delay before interaction.

Comment: Xpath was not dynamic. The issue was related to page being opened in a new tab on click of a link in the previous page and I was using the old window handle to find the element. I iterated to the next window handle then the xpath was correctly located and the button was clicked on running the script.

Comment: You should have mentioned that in your post at first place. Nobody could have guessed.

Comment: Even i notice that the page was opening in a new tab after I posted the question.

Answer (score 0):

Page was opened in a new tab in the window. Iterated to new window using below window handling code:

```
Set<String> windowIds = driver.getWindowHandles();
        Iterator<String> it = windowIds.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {          
            driver.switchTo().window(it.next());
        }
```

After iterating to new window handle and then using the driver object, element was correctly located on running the script.